# Magento or Headless Magento (React with Magento pwa or Magento 2 default is better)

Tags: magento2, pwa, default, react

I am new in Magento and I am preparing to start learning the cms. I'd like to know which has lower learning curve, just Magento or React+Magento. (I already know reactjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento first in my opinion. The PWA Studio it's just a front end tool that uses the Magento as a backend.

But, as Ben Crook said on the comments, learning only Magento, you will have to know many other things like RequireJS, KnockoutJS, LayoutXML, PHTML, jQuery. So, to improve my answer I would say that you can both learn Magento Backend and the PWA solution at same time. You don't need to learn the standard Magento Frontend, in this case.

Comment: But if Akshay already knows React then they will be able to work with the frontend and will only need to learn the backend. If they choose only Magento they will also have to know RequireJS, KnockoutJS, LayoutXML, PHTML, jQuery etc

Comment: That's true, I will update my answer